# Laravel InvalidArgumentException to create password reminder ability

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

in my web application i'm try to create simple password reminder ability by Laravel document about it such as [Laravel Document](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security#password-reminders-and-reset) or [http://laravel-recipes.com](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/73/creating-a-reminders-controller)

> To automatically generate a controller, you may use the auth:reminders-controller Artisan command, which will create a RemindersController.php file in your app/controllers directory.
>
> php artisan auth:reminders-controller

i get this error:

```
D:\xampp\htdocs\sample>php artisan auth:reminders-controller

  [InvalidArgumentException]
  Command "auth:reminders-controller" is not defined.
  Did you mean this?
      auth:clear-resets
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get that error because the `auth:reminders-controller` is an artisan command in Laravel 4.2, and you're probably using Laravel 5.*, where it is no longer supported.

Take a look [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/authentication#password-reminders-and-reset) because in Laravel 5 you don't need to create this functionality: it can be used just out of the box (or almost, still some database `migration` struggle is needed).

Comment: thanks sir, my post updated. please review that. thanks,

Comment: @mahdipishguy : But sir, this a totally diferent question. You are using your question just as a debug. The question was answered.